# Possible to use Office 365 AzureAD for SSO git https authentication?

Tags: git, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We're currently running our own git server with https access & basic authentication. When users interact with it via git bash they're prompted to authenticate against info in htpasswd, e.g.

```
git clone https://git.xxx.com/ProjectRepo.git
```

Recently, we've switched to Office 365 (comes with AzureAD) and started using OpenID to provide SSO for all the company webapps; however, with git being a "headless API" I'm stuck on how to integrate the git server into this.

Have any of you done an SSO setup on a private git server (without using Gitlab or similar), and if so how? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if this helps in your scenario? - https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-authentication-with-saml-single-sign-on

Comment: Github is a web frontend for managing git repositories (similar to gitlab), but I'm trying to get SSO on a private git server accessed directly via the git bash command line (thanks for chiming in though). The only potential path I've found so far is using LDAP on the git authentication to link up with AzureAD. Unfortunately, that's not included in the base pricing though from what I've read.

Comment: Hello @EmRa Are you still looking for help with this issue ?

Comment: Yes please! I have not found a workable solution yet.

Comment: @EmRa If you have Azure AD SAML SSO with Github enterprise, then personal access tokens are the way for API/Git client.

Comment: Not using Github though; this is to authenticate on our own company linux/git server hosted on AWS EC2. The problem is that git is CLI (so no browser interface to use OpenID), and to go LDAP requires MS Directory Services in addition to MS Azure AD (which costs extra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally cracked this. Git itself doesn't do authentication, it relies on the transport mechanism e.g. SSH or HTTP. When using "smart https" via apache, use apache basic authentication, and extend it with a custom/external script via `authnz-external` (I used python). In that script call the MS Access Library to authenticate the user with their MS365 account in Azure AD. This works even when using git on a headless machine with no browser.

- [Extend apache basic auth with a custom script](https://blog.g3rt.nl/custom-http-basic-authentication-apache.html)
- [MSAL SDK for python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python)